# Two amCharts graphs are not displaying on the same page with jQueryMobile framework on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, amcharts

I am creating a web application using the jQuery Mobile framework for iPad. In my application I need to display some charts, so I am using Javascript amCharts to draw charts.

In my application, on one page, I want to display a line chart, a bar chart and a HTML table. For a time, only one element will display. Either it will be a line chart or a bar chart or an HTML table. So I created three divs and put the charts and the HTML table in each div. I show or hide the divs via a menu selection. Please look at the [dummy application](http://questoons.com/nidhi-testing/demo/).

It is working perfectly in desktop browsers and Android tablets. When I test it on iPad, it is not working. It displays only the first line chart. If I change it to bar chart then it does not display the chart.

I am hiding and showing divs in javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('barChartDiv').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('lineChartDiv').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display='none';
```

So why does the second chart not appear on iPad? Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Is there any issue in jQuery Mobile and amCharts frameworks?

Any web link or source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call chart.validateNow() after you change display style of a div.